# How to create a MySQL table in Ubuntu compared to Windows?

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

Im helping out a Github project. Myself im coding in windows while the actual project runs live on a Ubuntu Webserver.
On my local repo i created an additional table creating a blank PHP file with this code and then just manually opening this (table.php) file once in the browser.

```
<?php    

$db = 'B5CGM';
$user='root';
$pw='147147';

//$user='root';
//$pw='';

$db_connect = mysql_connect("localhost", $user, $pw)
or die (mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db, $db_connect);

$sql = "CREATE TABLE tac_flightsize
(

    entry int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    gameid int,    
    shipid int,
    flightsize int,

    PRIMARY KEY (entry),
 )";

mysql_query($sql, $db_connect);

echo "done";


?>
```

However, this approach (with adjust $user and $pw) is not working on the live server. What am i doing wrong when it comes to comparing windows to ubuntu ?

thanks,

Comment: Most likely is has nothing to do with windows / ubuntu. Are you use that the username / password is the same on your local machine and on the live server? - Also, are you getting a error message? - And, I'd strongly recommend you to use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql as it is deprecated.

Comment: Typo, extra `,` after `PRIMARY KEY (entry)` - if that does not fix it you need to describe the error you encounter.

Comment: I dont encounter an error at all, i get the "done" echo, but the table is not created. Can i futher narrow / log it down ?

Comment: mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5, should use mysqli or PDO extension ( [ref](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) )

Comment: Make sure that error_reporting is turned on `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top of your page (just below <?php)  and perhaps validate/debug your queries.